# iOS 8 Transparent View with non-transparent subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to place non transparent content on top of a UIImageView. So I have a view with a transparent background which contains all the content. And I've placed it on top of imageview. I've set this view's background color to clearColor but still I can not get the desired effect.

This was clearly possible with iOS 6 SDK , but now I'm trying with iOS 8 SDK which does not give me what I want.

Check this app's screenshot 
[image]

I'm trying to achieve similar effect (a semi transparent view) with iOS 8 SDK. However I need to set opacity very low value which makes the view almost transparent. All I could achieve was very little transparency (something like alpha 0.9 even I set 0 ).

Comment: Show some code. How exactly are you presenting the "transparent" view that you want?

Comment: Above screenshot is from the same app I'm currently working on. I can not get this same effect in iOS 8.  Code which already worked doesn't work anymore. Above screenshot's transparent view has 0.6 alpha and clearColor set to it's container view. Now setting clearColor doesn't work anymore. It add's a darkGray kind of color with almost opaque transparency

Comment: OK, but you still didn't add any code.

Comment: OMFG what is your question?

Comment: @Andy who me? Or the OP?

Comment: @Fogmeister OP. So many twists in this question, I am really lost. What's going on?

Comment: @Andy yeah, I'm just trying to find out what code is being used. The screenshot in the question isn't the actual view that's going wrong. I'm thinking he may be trying to display a child view controller as opposed to just a view. But not sure.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by Using `UIVisualEffect` and `UIVisualEffectView` which are available from iOS 8 on.

This will provide a transparent view, as you said, without affecting the subviews.

Try this

```
UIVisualEffectView *blurredView =[[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight]];
[blurredView addSubview:self.mySubView];
```

and you can add your subviews and image views as well.

Comment: thnx. But I need the view to be transparent without being blurred. I need the content behind the view visible clearly without burring. Also need to support iOS 7

Comment: Oh! It can be done by setting the color of parent view to clear color [self.myParentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: It doesn't work now. I've tried and it worked in iOS 6 but not now. In my view I have (from bottom to top) Imageview-> uiview -> uiscrollview -> contents

Comment: and i had already set every possible view's background color to clearColor (except content's colours)

Comment: Oh! It can be done by setting the color of parent view to clear color [self.myParentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; and add another view with same size with your desired color and set alpha to that view: [self.myParentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIView* viewTransparent=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.myParentView.bounds];
    [viewTransparent setAlpha:0.5]
    [self.myParentView adddSubView:viewTransparent];

Comment: this is exactly I've done. It's not working anymore. Maximum transparency I can get is minimal and it apparently blurred.

Comment: Hoipe you are looking to  simply set color with alpha   [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.4]];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66111/discussion-between-sleepwalkerfx-and-sudhin-davis).

Comment: Simply I need a fully transparent view (like glass) on top of that UIImageView. No matter which view I set it's background to clearColor, I still get a very little transparency which is minimal

Answer (score 1):

Add your required views in the order, similar to the below code...

```
UIImageView* bottomImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
bottomImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImg.png"];
[self.view bottomImgView];

UIView* topTransparentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
topTransparentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[bottomImgView addSubview:topTransparentView];

UIView* subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[topTransparentView addSubview:subView];
```